# New line in youtube description

Tags: php, youtube

I have video in youtube:-

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozldow4IRv0
```

and i get its description like :-

```
function get_youtube_details($video_ID) {

    $json_output = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$video_ID."?v=2&alt=json");
    $json = json_decode($json_output, true);
    $video_description = $json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];
    echo $video_description;
}
```

Now, The wrong is when i print description in my site its not show me like this :-

```
ناليوم بداية جديدة مع قسم جديد خاص بألعاب الفيديو | Video Games وسأحاول بقدر الإمكان أن أجعله مرجع لمعلومات أجهزة ألعاب الفيديو وبعض الألعاب المشهورة ، وسنبدأ مع الجهاز الرائع Nintendo Wii U الذي أنتظرته من وقت طويل لأنه يحمل من الإبتكارات الكثير والكثير والذي من المتوقع أن يغير الكثير في عالم ألعاب الفيديو وكما تعلمون بأن شركة نتنتندو تركز دائماً على طريقة اللعب وليس الجرافيكس فقط وهذا هو سبب نجاح جهاز الـ Wii سابقاً مع أنه لا يحمل من القوة مايحمله المنافسين ،،،،


أضغط الرابط التالي لمشاركتها في تويتر مباشرة :

http://clicktotweet.com/u0_d0

المقال في المدونة :

http://www.saudnology.net/My/?p=6788

حساب الموقع في تويتر :

http://twitter.com/#!/saudnology

صفحة الموقع بالفيس بوك :

http://goo.gl/WBEm5

لمتابعة كل جديد من خلال الخلاصات :

http://feeds.feedburner.com/sh3r

صفحة الموقع في جوجل بلس :

https://plus.google.com/1046720901036...

- - - - - - - - - -

حسابي في تويتر :

http://twitter.com/abo_khamis

حسابي في الفيس بوك :

http://www.facebook.com/abo.khamis

حسابي في جوجل بلس :

http://gplus.to/saudAlkhamis
```

Its show me like :-

```
ناليوم بداية جديدة مع قسم جديد خاص بألعاب الفيديو | Video Games وسأحاول بقدر الإمكان أن أجعله مرجع لمعلومات أجهزة ألعاب الفيديو وبعض الألعاب المشهورة ، وسنبدأ مع الجهاز الرائع Nintendo Wii U الذي أنتظرته من وقت طويل لأنه يحمل من الإبتكارات الكثير والكثير والذي من المتوقع أن يغير الكثير في عالم ألعاب الفيديو وكما تعلمون بأن شركة نتنتندو تركز دائماً على طريقة اللعب وليس الجرافيكس فقط وهذا هو سبب نجاح جهاز الـ Wii سابقاً مع أنه لا يحمل من القوة مايحمله المنافسين ،،،، أضغط الرابط التالي لمشاركتها في تويتر مباشرة : http://clicktotweet.com/u0_d0 المقال في المدونة : http://www.saudnology.net/My/?p=6788 حساب الموقع في تويتر : http://twitter.com/#!/saudnology صفحة الموقع بالفيس بوك : http://goo.gl/WBEm5 لمتابعة كل جديد من خلال الخلاصات : http://feeds.feedburner.com/sh3r صفحة الموقع في جوجل بلس : https://plus.google.com/104672090103664280807 - - - - - - - - - - حسابي في تويتر : http://twitter.com/abo_khamis حسابي في الفيس بوك : http://www.facebook.com/abo.khamis حسابي في جوجل بلس : http://gplus.to/saudAlkhamis
```

No new line in paragraph, why.

I print it :-

```
<?php nl2br (get_youtube_details($keek_youtube_code)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `echo` to `return` in the function, so it is.

```
return $video_description;
```

and this

```
<?php nl2br (get_youtube_details($keek_youtube_code)); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo nl2br(get_youtube_details($keek_youtube_code)); ?>
```

Comment: No problem, but you should mark your answered questions as answered, so that the question is not in the unanswered section :)